# MySQL - How to display row value as column name using concat and group_concat

Tags: mysql, select, pivot-table, group-concat

**Table 1:**

```
id   | typeid | available|
0    | 1      | 12       |
0    | 2      | 44       |
```

**Table 2:**

```
typeid   | typename   |
1        | CL          |
2        | ML          |
```

I have a query using `concat` and `group_concat`:

```
select id,concat(group_concat(typename,available)) as types from table1
join table2 on table2.typeid=table1.typeid
```

I got the result as:

```
id | types   | 
0  | CL12,ML44 |
```

But I want to display it like this:

```
id   | CL   | ML    |
0    | 12   | 44    |
```

Is there any way to split the `group_concat` result to **columns heads**?

I want dynamically fetch data from table2. Some user can add data to table2. So hard-coding typename is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

You should use table pivoting. There is no PIVOT command in MySQL, so you can use this query -

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  MAX(IF(t2.typename = 'CL', t1.available, NULL)) AS CL,
  MAX(IF(t2.typename = 'ML', t1.available, NULL)) AS ML
FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.typeid = t2.typeid
GROUP BY
  t1.id;
```

[MySQL pivot tables (transform rows to columns)](http://buysql.com/mysql/12-how-to-pivot-tables.html).

Use GROUP_CONCAT function instead of MAX, if multiple `available` values are possible.

Comment: But now a challenge: How about if you don't know the typename values? Is it at all possible then?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, MAX(IF(b.typename = 'CL', a.available, 0)) CL, 
       MAX(IF(b.typename = 'ML', a.available, 0)) ML
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.typeid=b.typeid
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Use **SUM** function if you want to sum of the data from available column for particualr type else use the same query as ii is.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done only if you know all the typenames in advance -- otherwise, you'll need to find another way.  In databases that support returning result sets from stored procedures, it could be done with a stored proc.  But mysql doesn't support that.

If you know all the typenames, here's how you build the query:

```
SELECT
    id,
    SUM(IF(typename = 'CL', available, 0)) AS `CL`,
    SUM(IF(typename = 'ML', available, 0)) AS `ML`
FROM table1 join table2 on table1.typeid = table2.typeid
GROUP BY id
```