# MySQL select specific row values as column names

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

Here is my basic `participants` table (displayed as associative array):

```
[id] => 1
[campaign_id] => 41
[firstname] => Jeff
[lastname] => Berube
```

On another table, named `participants_custom`, I can add multiple custom data, that belongs to a `participants` row. Like this:

```
[id] => 51
[participant_id] => 1
[name] => textfield_bh423vjhgv
[data] => qwerty1

[id] => 52
[participant_id] => 1
[name] => textfield_IDRr2kzjZR59Xjw
[data] => qwerty2

[id] => 53
[participant_id] => 1
[name] => textfield_6kj5bhjjg
[data] => qwerty3
```

I am currently making a `join`, but it adds the only `name`, `participant_id`and `data` to my row. What I want is my query to return something like this:

```
[id] => 1
[campaign_id] => 41
[firstname] => Jeff
[lastname] => Berube
[textfield_bh423vjhgv] => qwerty1
[textfield_IDRr2kzjZR59Xjw] => qwerty2
[textfield_6kj5bhjjg] => qwerty3
```

Where row value `name` becomes a column, and `value`, it's value. **How can I make it?**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985470/mysql-how-to-display-row-value-as-column-name-using-concat-and-group-concat) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925445/mysql-select-dynamic-row-values-as-column-names-another-column-as-value), which was unsuccessful. I'm finding a way that would work with my situation. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        a.Campaign_ID,
        a.FirstName,
        a.LastName,
        MAX(CASE WHEN b.data = 'qwerty1' THEN b.Name END) qwerty1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN b.data = 'qwerty2' THEN b.Name END) qwerty2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN b.data = 'qwerty3' THEN b.Name END) qwerty3
FROM    Participants a
        INNER JOIN Participants_Custom b
            ON a.ID = b.Participant_ID
GROUP   BY  a.ID,
            a.Campaign_ID,
            a.FirstName,
            a.LastName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9602/1)

**UPDATE 1**

Since the values of `data` are unknown, a *dynamic sql* is much preferred.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN b.data = ''',
      data,
      ''' THEN b.Name ELSE NULL END) AS ',
      CONCAT('`',data, '`')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM Participants_Custom;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT  a.ID,
                           a.Campaign_ID,
                           a.FirstName,
                           a.LastName,', @sql, 
                  'FROM     Participants a
                            INNER JOIN Participants_Custom b
                                ON a.ID = b.Participant_ID
                    GROUP   BY  a.ID,
                                a.Campaign_ID,
                                a.FirstName,
                                a.LastName');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9602/4)

Comment: But b.data can be anything, not only qwerty1, querty2 or qwerty 3. How to if whatever the value in b.Name, is had to become a colum and have `value` as it's value?

Comment: And number of rows in `participants_custom` is variable, between 0 and 6 most of time.

Comment: then you need a dynamic sql, please wait `:D`