# Summerize sql count on post statuses

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a the following table structure:

Users table:

```
id       username                  
1           bob            
2           john             
3           harry
```

Posts table:

```
id       user_id          status        
1           1             4 
2           2             4    
3           3             2        
4           1             1      
5           2             1
```

If I wanted a summary of posts per user and cols of statuses, what is the most efficient sql to generate that?
Ex:

```
username       status 4  status 2 status 1  
bob             1         0        1
john            1         0        1  
harry           0         1        0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - How to display row value as column name using concat and group\_concat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985470/mysql-how-to-display-row-value-as-column-name-using-concat-and-group-concat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT users.username
, sum(if(posts.status=4,1,0)) as `status 4`
, sum(if(posts.status=2,1,0)) as `status 2`
, sum(if(posts.status=1,1,0)) as `status 1`
 FROM users, posts
 WHERE users.id=posts.user_id
 GROUP BY users.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try somthing like this:-

```
SELECT A.USERNAME, 
CASE WHEN STATUS = 4 THEN COUNT(B.STATUS) AS STATUS4 ELSE 0 END,
CASE WHEN STATUS = 2 THEN COUNT(B.STATUS) AS STATUS2 ELSE 0 END,
CASE WHEN STATUS = 1 THEN COUNT(B.STATUS) AS STATUS1 ELSE 0 END,
FROM USERS INNER JOIN POSTS
ON USERS.ID = POSTS.USER_ID
GROUP BY USERS.ID;
```

This might help you.