# how to display attendance report based on roll number and i want everything to be dynamic

Tags: php, mysql, pivot-table

I am working on Classes management project. Everything is done successfully but only stuck with attendance report work.

> i want result like this

[image]

My table structure:

[image]

Comment: You are looking for a pivot query, possibly a dynamic one, if the number of months needs to be flexible based on the data set.  Are the number of months fixed in your problem?

Comment: i have tried lot of things but not getting desired result. i am working on this since last 7 days. finally posted a question here.

Comment: months will be fixed like report for march 2017

Comment: This might be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13985470/2298301

Comment: The accepted answer on the duplicate link describes both static (columns are known in advance) and dynamic (columns are not known in advance) pivoting in MySQL. It may be more efficient to do such transformations in the application and not in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE mp_attendence (atid int, atdisplayname varchar(9), atroll varchar(9), atstatus varchar(9), atdate date, atbatch varchar(9)) ;

INSERT INTO mp_attendence (atid, atdisplayname, atroll, atstatus, atdate, atbatch) VALUES (1, 'lavkush', '1', 'absent', '2017-03-01', 'p1'), (2, 'dhanji', '2', 'present', '2017-03-01', 'p1'), (3, 'lavkush', '1', 'present', '2017-03-02', 'p1'), (4, 'dhanji', '2', 'present', '2017-03-02', 'p1'), (5, 'lavkush', '1', 'present', '2017-03-04', 'p1'), (6, 'dhanji', '2', 'absent', '2017-03-04', 'p1'), (7, 'lavkush', '1', 'present', '2017-03-05', 'p1'), (8, 'dhanji', '2', 'absent', '2017-03-05', 'p1') ;

SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT(
  '(case when atstatus = ''',
  atstatus,
  ''' then (atstatus) end) AS ',
   replace (DATE_FORMAT(atdate, '%d %M %Y'), ' ', '')
)
) INTO @sql
from mp_attendence;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT atdisplayname, atroll, ', @sql, ' from mp_attendence
group by atroll');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

From above query i achieve this result but i want to combine same dates like 1st march result should be in same row.

[result achieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iF2l.jpg)

Comment: [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3daa9/36)